# Загрузка файла с расширением .php

Tags: php

Как сделать, файл index.php (к примеру), качался в PHP скрипт по PHP коду?
Например. Есть сайт, там стоит php скрипт, на загрузку, и он с другого сайта качает другой скрипт. Как то так)

Comment: Пожалуйста, по точнее сформулируйте свой вопрос. Но могу предположить, что вы имеете ввиду функцию include.

Comment: Нет, с другого сайта, загрузку в другой сайт

Comment: вы хотите загрузить удаленный скрипт и запустить его в файле через который вы его скачиваете сразу после скачивания ?

Comment: @Alex нет, чтобы он просто загружался в другой скрипт

Comment: другой скрипт - это сторонний файл php ?

Comment: @Alex да, к примеру index.php

Comment: @Snegan `file_get_contents('http://сайт.ру/index.php');` Только надо понимать, что исходный php-код вы не скачаете ничем. Вы можете скачать только __результат работы__ файла index.php.

Comment: @Эдуард это смотря как он  обратится. по ссылке да, Вы правы, не получит, но он может и фтп поднять)